# Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem to figure out a day of the year

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

To be completely transparent: this is a homework question that I am requesting help with.

The question says, "The Julian calendar has 365 days unless the year number satisfies x ≅ 0 (mod 4), in which case the year has 366 days".

My understanding so far is that if the year is divisible by 4, it is a leap year and has 366 days.

The question then goes on, "Explain why 11th February in year X of the Julian calendar is a Friday if x ≅ 1732 (mod 28).

Here is what I have so far,

1732 % 28 = 24
X % 28 = 24

[(X % 28) + 4] % 4 == 0

Therefore I know that X is divisible by 4 and is thus a leap year (has 366 days). But what do I do next?

Comment: Don't you first need to know the day of the week of a particular date?

Comment: You might mean the 11th OF february instead of 11th february